# Build "Heartbeat" Observable from Unpredictable Source Observable

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-java3

I have an Observable, `source`, that may emit items at unpredictable times. I'm trying to use it to build another Observable that reliably emits its values every 500ms.

Let's say that `source` emits values at these times:

- 100ms - first item
- 980ms - second item
- 1020ms - third item
- 1300ms - fourth item, etc.

I'd like to "smooth" this stream, so that I get outputs like:

- 500ms - first item
- 1000ms - second item
- 1500ms - third item
- 2000ms - fourth item

A naive approach might be to just add a delay in between emissions of source items. But, that won't create evenly spaced intervals, like I want.

I've tried various combinations of `.timer()`, `.interval()`, and `.flatMap()`, but nothing promising, yet.

Comment: What happens if the `source` emits 3 times in a 500ms interval, e.g. emits at 100, 200 and 300? What happens if it does not emit for 1000ms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For a source emitting faster than your interval

`zip` your source with an `interval` of the required time span.

```ts
zip(source, interval(500)).pipe(
  map(([value, _]) => value)  // only emit the source value
)
```

[image]

`zip` emits the 1st item from `source` with the 1st item from `interval`, then the 2nd item from `source` with the 2nd item from `interval` and so on. If the output observable should only emit when `interval` emits, the Nth value from `source` has to arrive **before** the Nth value from `interval`.

**Potential Problem:**
If your `source` emits slower than `interval` at some point (i.e. the Nth value from `source` arrives **after** the Nth value from `interval`) then `zip` will emit directly without waiting for the next time `interval` emits.

```ts
// the 5th/6th value from source arrive after the 5th/6th value from interval
                                              v    v
source:       -1--------2-3---4---------------5----6-----
interval:     -----1-----2-----3-----4-----5-----6-----7-
zip output:   -----1-----2-----3-----4--------5----6-----
                   ✓     ✓     ✓     ✓        ⚠️    ⚠️
// emits 5 and 6 don't happen when interval emits
```

#### For a source emitting at any rate

```ts
function emitOnInterval<T>(period: number): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) =>
    defer(() => {
      let sourceCompleted = false;
      const queue = source.pipe(
        tap({ complete: () => (sourceCompleted = true) }),
        scan((acc, curr) => (acc.push(curr), acc), []) // collect all values in a buffer
      );
      return interval(period).pipe(
        withLatestFrom(queue), // combine with the latest buffer
        takeWhile(([_, buffer]) => !sourceCompleted || buffer.length > 0), // complete when the source completed and the buffer is empty
        filter(([_, buffer]) => buffer.length > 0), // only emit if there is at least on value in the buffer
        map(([_, buffer]) => buffer.shift()) // take the first value from the buffer
      );
    });
}

source.pipe(
  emitOnInterval(500)
)
```

```ts
// the 5th/6th value from source arrive after the 5th/6th value from interval
                                              v    v
source:       -1--------2-3---4---------------5----6-----
interval:     -----1-----2-----3-----4-----5-----6-----7-
output:       -----1-----2-----3-----4-----------5-----6-
                   ✓     ✓     ✓     ✓           ✓     ✓   
// all output emits happen when interval emits
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-qdlktm?file=index.ts

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try this:

```js
const src$ = merge(
  timer(100).pipe(mapTo(1)),
  timer(980).pipe(mapTo(2)),
  timer(1020).pipe(mapTo(3)),
  timer(1300).pipe(mapTo(4))
);

src$
  .pipe(
    bufferTime(500),
    mergeAll()
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

`bufferTime` is used in order to create a timer that will emit at constant intervals, irrespective of the emitted values. Then `mergeAll` is used to *explode* the array resulted from `bufferTime`.

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-playground91?file=examples/sampletime.ts).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `combineLatest`, `interval` and `throttle` - you add a second observable, `interval` with the time between calls you want (e.g. 500ms), so every 500ms your observable will emit (when used with `combineLatest`), now it will emit the values every 500ms **and** every time the original `source` emits, so you can add `throttle` in a pipe and that will cause the interval to throttle:

```
combineLatest([source, timer(5000)])
  .pipe(
    throttle(() => interval(5000)),
    tap(([value]) => {
      console.log("emitted", value, new Date().getSeconds());
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

(`tap` is not required here, just added to demonstrate)

Comment: Why do you use 5 seconds?

Comment: I was playing around with the code, so 5 seconds was easier to test with than 0.5 seconds, the interval doesn’t really matter, as long as you set both the interval and the throttle to the same value